# Jetpack Compose, ModalBottomSheetLayout and content height

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

In my app, I'd like to use a `ModalBottomSheetLayout`. In my sheet content it, I'd like to use multiple screens :

```kotlin
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    modifier = Modifier,
    content = { /* Some content */ },
    sheetContent = {

        Crossfade(
            modifier = Modifier,
            targetState = someState
        ) { state ->

            when (state) {

                A -> FirstScreen()

                B -> SecondScreen()

            }

        }

    }
)
```

The issue is that if my next screen is smaller than my previous, the animation makes that the bottom sheet is falling down.

I've tried to use `Modifier.animateContentSize` or `Modifier.wrapContent` on the `Crossfade`, or use a `AnimatedContent`, but the result is always the same

Anyone knows how to resolve that issue ? Thank for your help

Comment: Have had this issue also. the bottom of the sheet appears to "jump" slightly and the content under the sheet is visible for a brief moment.

Comment: @TylerTurnbull To solve that, I had to rewrite the entire code of ModalBottomSheetLayout but with a background behind which follow the sheet through a ConstraintLayout...